# Auto width for child div within a parent container div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have found the following jsfiddle on this site which 90% answers my query.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yaLMk/4)

However I want to be able to include margins on the inner divs. I've tried amending the calculationg to account for margins but I can't get it to work without the inner divs going on a new line or overflowing.

jquery code is

```
var containerW = $('.container').width();
var innerCount = $('.container .inner').length;

$('.inner').css({
    width: containerW / innerCount
})
```

html is

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='inner' style='background : #FF0000;'></div>
    <div class='inner' style='background : #00FF00;'></div>
    <div class='inner' style='background : #0000FF;'></div>
    <div class='inner' style='background : orange;'></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    background : #bbb;
}
.inner {
    float:left;
    height:100%;
    min-width:30px;
}
```

I only want to be able to put left and right margin so the inner divs appear spaced out.

Thanks

Comment: post the code in your question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are giving margin to  the `.inner` class like `margin:5px;` then try in js like

```
$('.inner').css({
    width: (containerW / innerCount)-10
})
```

because if we are giving `margin :5px` means left-right its 5-5 , so total `10px` for one inner div, so we have to minus it from its width;

Comment: I can it to work when I do that typing the actual number but I've tried to amend the code so it declares another variable based on the left-margin. It doesn't however work. 'code'var containerW = $('.container').width();
var innerCount = $('.container .inner').length;
var containerM = $('.container .inner').css("margin-left");



$('.inner').css({
    width:  (containerW  / innerCount) - (containerM * 2) 
})'code'

Comment: I think Ive got it now. I've added parseint to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of setting the css width, you can use jquery "outerWidth" function. So, your jquery code should be:

```
var containerW = $('.container').width();
var innerCount = $('.container .inner').length;
$('.inner').outerWidth(containerW / innerCount, true);
```

The second argument in outerWidth tells whether to include margin in width computation or not.

Comment: I can get that all to work in jsfiddle, but I have tried to translate it across to my site and can't get it work. Do I need to call the JS in a particular way? (I dont have much JS experience). Do I need to make that calculation a function and call it when I load my page?

Comment: Are you using the latest version of jQuery? This will work only with jQuery1.8 or higher.